# Execute command from string containing spaces

Tags: bash, whitespace

How to execute command from string containing spaces?

```
$ ls "xxx yyy"
a.exe

$ X="./xxx yyy/a.exe" ; $X
-bash: ./xxx: No such file or directory

$ X='./xxx yyy/a.exe' ; $X
-bash: ./xxx: No such file or directory

$ X="./xxx\ yyy/a.exe" ; $X
-bash: ./xxx\: No such file or directory
```

How? Any ideas?

---

UPD. Found: `$ X="./xxx yyy/a.exe" ; "$X"`.

---

UPD2. <s>But I cannot pass arguments to it. This: `$ X="./xxx yyy/a.exe" ; "$X" xxx` does not pass `xxx` to `$X`. Hot to do it? Any help? This `$ X="./xxx\ yyy/a.exe" ; eval $X xxx` seems to work, but why there is a need to use `eval`? Is it possible to avoid `eval`?</s>

To pass arguments use `$ X="./xxx yyy/a.exe" ; "$X" xxx`.

Comment: "`$ X="./xxx yyy/a.exe" ; "$X" xxx` does not pass `xxx` to `$X`" ... that works fine enough for me.

Comment: @muru Ah, right! Thanks! I've mistakenly used `"$(X)" xxx` instead of `"$X" xxx`.